# Phonegap/Iphone issue with Iframes

Tags: jquery, xcode, cordova

I have a jquery mobile app that i am trying to wrap in phonegap, and
everything is working fine except for behavior of an iframe.
outside of PhoneGap, the behavior works as expected.

Now i have imported the project into Xcode/Phonegap

On the ios simulator (or phone), the device now opens up a new browser window instead of just behaving like a typical iframe works.

i have an iframe which essentially gets loaded like this:
$('#myiframe').attr("src", 'http://www.myurl.com');
$('#myiframe').load( alert('frame loaded');

I've heard about adding a config.xml file to my xcode project but I haven't been able to find a firm solution.

Please help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the src domain under the ExternalHosts key in PhoneGap.plist. Note - if the domain you put as the iframe src is re-directed, you will need to add that domain in the ExternalHosts key as well. For example, in Canada, www.google.com re-directs to www.google.ca, so you will have to add that domain as well. Another example, phonegap.com re-directs to www.phonegap.com. This domain value must be exact, wild-card support is not available.